# Putting a Resource Creation call inside a Static block , will that make it create only once for the Entire Application

Tags: java

I have taken the below line  from one of the blog

**The only way JAXB would be that slow compared to the others is if he's
creating a new JAXBContext for each call**

**Here the author mentions that , if JAXBContext   is created for every new call then it will be slow**

I am working on a Java EE based web application where they can be many users at a time .

So to avoid this , if i put that creating JAXBContext call inside a static block , will it create JAXBContext only once ?

```
public class MessageParser {
    private static JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
    static {
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XML.class.getPackage().getName());
        } 
catch (Exception x) {

        }
    }
    public static Message parse(String requestStr) throws Exception {
        Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
         // Does Some processing and returns the message 
        return  message;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use singleton pattern

For example:

```
public class JAXBContextFactory {

    private static JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    public static final JAXBContext getInstance() throws JAXBException {
        if(jaxbContext == null) {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XML.class.getPackage().getName());
        }

        return jaxbContext;
    }

}
```

Then on you class:

```
public class MessageParser {

    public static Message parse(String requestStr) throws Exception {
        Unmarshaller um = JAXBContextFactory.getInstance().createUnmarshaller();
         // Does Some processing and returns the message 
        return  message;
    }

}
```

So you can use single `JAXBContext` object via `JAXBContextFactory.getInstance()` method in you application

[The JAXBContext class is thread safe, but the Marshaller, Unmarshaller, and Validator classes are not thread safe.](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use this real singleton thread-safe solution:

```
public class JAXBContextBeanName {

    private static JAXBContextBeanName instance;
    private static JAXBContext context;

    public JAXBContextBeanName() {
    }

    public static synchronized JAXBContextBeanName getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new JAXBContextBeanName();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized JAXBContext getContext() throws Exception {
        try {
            if (context == null) {
                context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {

        }
        return context;
    }
}
```

Then use it with following for marshaling:

```
JAXBContextBeanName singleton = JAXBContextBeanName.getInstance();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = singleton.getContext();
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
synchronized (marshaller) {
    marshaller.marshal(beanObject, document);
}
```

and for unmarshaling:

```
JAXBContextBeanName singleton = JAXBContextBeanName.getInstance();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = singleton.getContext();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
synchronized(unmarshaller) {
    asd = (ASD) unmarshaller.unmarshal(document));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is "yes", however this structure makes it difficult to deal with exceptions.  I would structure the code this way:

```
public class MessageParser {
    private static JAXBContext jc = null;
    public static Message parse(String requestStr) throws Exception {
        if(jc == null) {
            try {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XML.class.getPackage().getName());
            } 
            catch (Exception x) {
                //now you are in the context of the method so can deal with the exception properly
                //or just throw it to let the caller deal with it.
            }
        }
        if(jc != null) {
            Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
             // Does Some processing and returns the message 
            return  message;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is , for the entire Web Application (requests from different users  ) will there be only one JAXBContext existing ?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, there will be.  You need to be careful in terms of thread synchronisation.  In web app, each request is processed in a separate thread, so you should probably syncrhonise creating `jaxbContext`.  Depending on the deployment, you may end up with multiple copies of the app being loaded using separate instances of the classloader, in which case there will be one copy per classloader.

Comment: This is great , as it gives only one instance of it through the application , but then why do people use Singleton ?

Comment: "Singleton" is exactly what you are trying to do, just without calling it this way.  "Singleton" refers to having one static instance of some class and then referring to it.